# Hyperledger fabric join-channel: Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [] creator org [Org1MSP]

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

New Peer is unable to join the channel.
I have created a new peer in an existing organization and when I am running 
`docker network inspect bridge` I can see that new peer is part of the organization.

When I am trying this peer to join the channel (mychannel) it is throwing below error.
`Error: 2 UNKNOWN: access denied: channel [] creator org [Org1MSP]`

In the above error, channel is an empty string while I am sending the `mychannel` as an argument.

I am using the [join-channel script of balance transfer](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release/balance-transfer/app/join-channel.js). It is working perfectly fine for the peers which created during the network creation.

Any idea why it is taking an empty string?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the reason.

Actually, the new peer is generated using different CA.

Previously I moved my organization's crypto-config directory to a different folder and then when I created new Peer it created new certificates for complete organization.

But I don't know the significance of the error as it must be different in this scenario.